# symfony view: share layout.php between apps, but with differences

Tags: view, symfony1, symfony-1.4, slot

I have several symfony apps (different vhosts) with the same skin, i.e. `layout.php`. I have one instance of the `layout.php` and asset files "someplace," and I symlink them into each app.

I would like to use Google Analytics with these apps, which requires each app to include its own key. How can I inject it into the `layout.php?`

Best answer I could come up with is to set the analytics JS code as a slot in `myActions::preExecute()` and extend `sfActions`. Anyone have a better idea?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not just use an `sfConfig` value to set the tracker id? Then the value can be configured in the app.yml file for each app.